# Split button for WPF that works in Win7 and Win8 themes

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Anyone know of a WPF split button that looks like a regular button in both the Win7 theme and the Win8 theme? I'm using one that looks good for Win7 but sticks out like a sore thumb in Win8:

[image: weird button]

I've tried the [WPF Splitbutton project on codeplex](http://wpfsplitbutton.codeplex.com/), the [Banana Splitbutton](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/07/06/banana-splitbutton-a-wpf-specific-fix-for-splitbutton-and-some-code-analysis-improvements-for-the-silverlight-version-too.aspx) and the [splitbutton in the Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SplitButton).

Is there anything out there that gives an Win7-themed button in Win7 and a Win8-themed button in Win8?

I need the control to have a bindable Command property and show a context menu when the down arrow is pressed.

Comment: If it's just a matter of aesthetics, you could take whatever splitbutton you've found that already does what you require and just change the style template to make it look different. Is that all you're after?

Comment: That would work if it changes styles correctly when used in the Win7/Win8 theme.

Comment: Are you trying to have a different style for win7 and another different one for win8? The style template should be fine between them if built correctly. Maybe some visual example of what you're after may help clarify the overall requirement here.

Comment: @ChrisW. Edited to show the problem. What I'm after is a standard look on the button when used in both Win7 and Win8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with Sten's approach: nesting a button inside another button. I used a user control to make it re-usable, putting all the elements in the control template so it could put arbitrary content inside the button.

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="VidCoder.Controls.SplitButton"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  Loaded="SplitButton_OnLoaded">
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
      <Button 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="mainButton" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom" 
        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
        <Button.Content>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="True">
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
            <Rectangle Width="1" Fill="#111111" Margin="0,2" />
            <Button Click="OnArrowClick">
              <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                  <Grid Background="Transparent" Name="buttonGrid">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                  </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Button.Template>
              <Button.Content>
                <Path Data="M 0,0 L 8,0 L 4,4 Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="4 0 3 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </Button.Content>
            </Button>
          </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu Name="buttonMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </Button.ContextMenu>
      </Button>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

The codebehind exposes the menu item collection and Command property:

```
public partial class SplitButton : UserControl
{
    private Button button;

    private ObservableCollection<object> menuItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<object>();

    public Collection<object> MenuItemsSource { get { return this.menuItemsSource; } }

    public SplitButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command",
        typeof (ICommand),
        typeof (SplitButton),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandChanged));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.NewValue != eventArgs.OldValue)
        {
            var splitButton = dependencyObject as SplitButton;

            if (splitButton.button != null)
            {
                splitButton.button.Command = eventArgs.NewValue as ICommand;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnArrowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonMenu = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(this.button);

        if (this.menuItemsSource.Count > 0 && buttonMenu != null)
        {
            buttonMenu.IsOpen = !buttonMenu.IsOpen;
            buttonMenu.PlacementTarget = this.button;
            buttonMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
        }
    }

    private void SplitButton_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.button = this.Template.FindName("mainButton", this) as Button;
        if (this.Command != null)
        {
            this.button.Command = this.Command;
        }
    }
}
```

In use:

```
<controls:SplitButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding TestCommand}">
    <controls:SplitButton.MenuItemsSource>
        <MenuItem Header="ham" Command="{Binding TestCommand2}" />
        <MenuItem Header="sandwiches" />
        <MenuItem Header="yum" />
    </controls:SplitButton.MenuItemsSource>
    <TextBlock Padding="4" Text="Testing" />
</controls:SplitButton>
```

[image: Splitbutton usage example]

Answer (score 1):

You can always make your own out of two standard buttons and it's not that hard - just but a button within the button, customize the style of the inner one to lack border, have the drop-down triangle and have "transparent" background (not the same as {x:null} background which causes click-through)

Roughly something like this:

```
<Button Style="outerStyle">
  <Button.Content>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Click Me</Label>
        <Button Style="{innerStyleWithTransparentBackground}"> ▼ </Button>
     </StackPanel>
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

If you use a lot of split buttons (do it anyway) you can put this construct in a user control with a couple routed events, otherwise you can nest it in your other code.

It's not the most elegant solution but it's probably one of the simplest ones you'd find.

Comment: This has many problems. The first of which is that when you click on the nested button the click handler for both buttons fires. Second is that the nested button is not flush with the sides of the main button. Third is that simply setting a background color doesn't get rid of the Button outline/style.

Comment: the first: not true, if your handler declares the event "handled" and its background is not null. null background can cause click-through
the second: some styling is needed for the button
the third: as you can see in the faked example these buttons have their styles set, not the backgrounds alone

Comment: Okay so we now have to change the button control template and eliminate all content padding on the outer one? And then I guess rely on whatever is using that control to put the padding back in? As for the sub-button you'd have to write a new control template for that as well to get rid of the edge, but then you have to write back in code to do hover/pressed coloring, etc. I don't really like this approach.

Comment: For the outer you don't have to style anything and that's the goal - to reuse the system default button style.  For the inner you'll have to make a very simple control template, such as <Border Background="Transparent"><ContentPresenter/></Border>. If you wish to get rid of the padding you can set the RenderTransform to move it a couple pixels right. You could do fancier things, such as change the border background on mouseover etc.
I did say this is not an elegant solution but it's definitely doable and faster than most others

Comment: I worked on this a lot today and got a `SplitButton` user control going based loosely on this advice. It works alright because the outer button doesn't have a lot of padding. I chose this approach because it's the most theme-flexible: any time the button changes looks due to a theme this works. I had to do a few other clever things to get it to work; once I get it cleaned up I'll post what I did.

Answer (score 0):

The "sticking out like a sore thumb" is a result of how wpf controls resolve their style. By default (meaning if you have not supplied a Style via the Style property), the splitbutton will go up the resource tree until it finds a style with the TargetType of splitButton and an implicit style x:Key of "{x:Type SplitButton}". If it can't find a style for your splitbutton, it will look in the theme file for whatever windows theme you are currently using. In win7 this is usually Aero.NormalColor.xaml. I'm not sure for win8 but I'd imagine Metro.NormalColor.xaml (correct me if I'm wrong). If it can't find a style in the theme dictionary, it will look in Generic.xaml. Anyways, what you want to do is define an implicit style for your control at a level in the resource tree that make sense (probably at Window if it is a standalone or Page if the xaml is hosted in a browser/>. This will be the style that is always used (when style is not explicitly defined).

Example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_basics

Comment: But I don't want to just pick a style and have it used at all times. I want it to vary based on what theme the user has. Is my only option to style my whole app to always look the same no matter what OS or theme the user is using?

Comment: No, that is definitely not your only option. You can actually add styles to the windows themes. see "Defining Resources at theme level" in the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx